# Sorting Items from table in Wordpress using WP_List_Table Sorts Number Column as Text

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I am using [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) to create a custom plugin. I am using code copied from another source, and everything is working fine, except when sorting the table according to the ID column or Order Number Column, that are "int" defined in My SQL database.

Here is Class Code Class Inheriting WP_List_Table:

```
 <?php


if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}
class TT_Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    function __construct(){
        global $status, $page;

        //Set parent defaults
        parent::__construct( array(
        'singular'  => 'movie',     //singular name of the listed records
        'plural'    => 'movies',    //plural name of the listed records
        'ajax'      => false        //does this table support ajax?
       ) );       
    }
    function column_default($item, $column_name){
    switch($column_name){
        case 'id':
        case 'name_english':
        case 'name_arabic':
        case 'ordering_number':
            return $item[$column_name];
        default:
            return print_r($item,true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }
    function column_id($item){    
    //Build row actions
        $actions = array(
            'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&movie=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['id']),
            'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&movie=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['id']),
        );
        //Return the title contents
        return sprintf('%1$s <span style="color:silver">%2$s</span>%3$s',
        /*$1%s*/ $item['id'],
        /*$2%s*/ $item['ID'],
        /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }
    function column_cb($item){
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[]" value="%2$s" />',
            /*$1%s*/ $this->_args['singular'],  //Let's simply repurpose the table's singular label ("movie")
            /*$2%s*/ $item['id']                //The value of the checkbox should be the record's id
        );
    }
    function get_columns(){
        $columns = array(
        'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
        'id'     => 'ID',
        'name_english'    => 'English Name',
        'name_arabic'  => 'Arabic Name',
        'ordering_number' => 'Order Number'
        );
        return $columns;
    }
function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
        'id'     => array('id',true),     //true means it's already sorted
        'name_english'    => array('name_english',true),
        'name_arabic'  => array('name_arabic',true),
        'ordering_number'  => array('ordering_number',true)
    );
        return $sortable_columns;
    }
    function get_bulk_actions() {
    $actions = array(
        'delete'    => 'Delete'
    );
    return $actions;
    }
    function process_bulk_action() {

    //Detect when a delete action is being triggered...
    if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) {

       if( is_array ($_GET['movie'])) {
              foreach ($_GET['movie'] as $value) {
             global $wpdb;
               $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare ("DELETE FROM " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " WHERE id = " .$value));
                    if (file_exists(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'appfiles/images/categories/' . $value . '.jpg' )) {
                        unlink(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'appfiles/images/categories/' . $value . '.jpg');
                        }
                 }
               echo '<div class="updated">  <p>Many Categories have been deleted.</p></div>';

           } else{
             global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare ("DELETE FROM " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " WHERE id = " .$_GET['movie']));
                   if (file_exists(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'appfiles/images/categories/' . $_GET['movie'] . '.jpg' )) {
                        unlink(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'appfiles/images/categories/' . $_GET['movie'] . '.jpg');
                        }
               echo '<div class="updated">  <p>One Category has been deleted.</p></div>';
           }
 }

    //Detect when a edit action is being triggered...
      if( 'edit'===$this->current_action() ) {
            global $wpdb;
            $english_name = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("select name_english from " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " where id= " .$_GET['movie']) );
            $arabic_name = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("select name_arabic from " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " where id= " .$_GET['movie']) );
            $order_number = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("select ordering_number from " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " where id= " .$_GET['movie']) );
         echo "<h1> Edit Category </h1><br><br><br><br><br>"; ?> 

<form class="cp-club-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?PHP echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=categories-tropicana-plugin&action=editing' ); ?>">

             <table style="width:50%">
           <tr> <td>Category ID:</td> <td><input name="editID" type="text" value='<?PHP echo $_GET['movie']; ?>' readonly> </td> <td> Do not Touch</td></tr>
           <tr> <td>English Name:</td> <td><input name="english_name" type="text" value='<?PHP echo $english_name; ?>'> </td> <td> First Language</td></tr> 
           <tr> <td>Arabic Name:</td> <td><input name="arabic_name" type="text" value='<?PHP echo $arabic_name; ?>'> </td><td> Second Language</td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Order Number:</td> <td><input name="order_number" type="number" value='<?PHP echo $order_number; ?>'> </td><td> Its Order in appearance in the mobile app</td></tr>
<tr><td>Assigned Image</td><td> <img src="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/tropicana-delivery/appfiles/images/categories/<?php echo $_GET['movie'] ?>.jpg" alt="Category Image" style="width:150px;"> </td><td>Best Dimensions: </td></tr>
 <tr> <td></td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></td><td> <input type="submit" name="submitediting" value='Save'> </td>    
         </table>
 </form>
         <?php
        wpdie();
        }
 // Detect if editing is saved & done
  if ('editing'===$this->current_action()) {
      if(isset($_POST['submitediting'])) {

         if ($_FILES['file']['size'] != 0) {
        // Check filetype
         if($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpeg'){
               die('Unsupported filetype uploaded. Only JPEG is allowed for Mobile Technical Reasons');
            }
             // Upload file
           if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'appfiles/images/categories/' . $_POST['editID'] . '.jpg')){
            die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.!!!');
             }
          }
         global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare ("UPDATE " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " SET name_english= '".$_POST['english_name']."', name_arabic = '".   $_POST['arabic_name']."', ordering_number= ".$_POST['order_number']." WHERE id = " .$_POST['editID']));
          echo '<div class="updated">  <p>Edited Successfully</p></div>';
      }}
// If Add new Button is Pressed
  if ('new'===$this->current_action()) {
       echo "<h1> Add New Category </h1><br><br><br><br><br>"; ?> 

  <form class="cp-club-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?PHP echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=categories-tropicana-plugin&action=newadded' ); ?>">

             <table style="width:50%">
           <tr> <td>Category ID:</td> <td><input name="editID" type="text" value='Automatic' readonly> </td> <td> Do not Touch</td></tr>
           <tr> <td>English Name:</td> <td><input name="english_name" type="text" value=''> </td> <td> First Language</td></tr> 
           <tr> <td>Arabic Name:</td> <td><input name="arabic_name" type="text" value=''> </td><td> Second Language</td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Order Number:</td> <td><input name="order_number" type="number" value=''> </td><td> Its Order in appearance in the mobile app</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Assigned Image</td><td>  </td><td>Best Dimensions: </td></tr>
           <tr> <td></td><td><input type="file" name="filenew" id="file"></td><td> <input type="submit" name="submitnew" value='Save'> </td>    
         </table>
         </form>
         <?php

         wpdie();
          }

    // Handling New Category insert

     if ('newadded'===$this->current_action()) {
        if(isset($_POST['submitnew'])) {

          global $wpdb;
          $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare ("INSERT INTO " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " (name_english,name_arabic,ordering_number) VALUES ( '".$_POST['english_name']."', '".$_POST['arabic_name']."', ".$_POST['order_number'].")"));

           if ($_FILES['filenew']['size'] != 0) {
          // Check filetype
         if($_FILES['filenew']['type'] != 'image/jpeg'){
               die('Unsupported filetype uploaded. Only JPEG is allowed for Mobile Technical Reasons');
            }
             // Upload file
           if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filenew']['tmp_name'], plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'appfiles/images/categories/' . $wpdb->insert_id . '.jpg')){
            die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.!!!');
             }
          }

        echo '<div class="updated">  <p>Added Successfully</p></div>';
       }}

      }


     function prepare_items() {
        global $wpdb; //This is used only if making any database queries

       $per_page = 10;

      $columns = $this->get_columns();
      $hidden = array();
      $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

       $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);

      $this->process_bulk_action();

      global $wpdb;
        $data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables'], ARRAY_A);

         if( isset($_GET['s']) ){ echo $_GET['s'];
         $data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM " .$GLOBALS['categoriestables']. " WHERE name_english LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%' OR name_arabic LIKE '%".$_GET['s']."%'" , ARRAY_A);
          }


       function usort_reorder($a,$b){
          $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'id'; //If no sort, default to title
          $order = (!empty($_REQUEST['order'])) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc'; //If no order, default to asc
          $result = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]); //Determine sort order
          return ($order==='asc') ? $result : -$result; //Send final sort direction to usort
        }
      usort($data, 'usort_reorder');

      $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();

      $total_items = count($data);

       $data = array_slice($data,(($current_page-1)*$per_page),$per_page);

      $this->items = $data;

       $this->set_pagination_args( array(
        'total_items' => $total_items,                  //WE have to calculate the total number of items
        'per_page'    => $per_page,                     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        'total_pages' => ceil($total_items/$per_page)   //WE have to calculate the total number of pages
       ) );
      }


      }
```

And here is how we use this Class

```
//Create an instance of our package class...
$testListTable = new TT_Example_List_Table();
//Fetch, prepare, sort, and filter our data...
$testListTable->prepare_items();

?>
<div class="wrap">

    <!-- Forms are NOT created automatically, so you need to wrap the table in one to use features like bulk actions -->
    <form id="movies-filter" method="get">
        <div id="icon-users" class="icon32"></div>
        <h2>Manage Your App Categories <a href="<?PHP echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=categories-tropicana-plugin&action=new' ); ?>" class="add-new-h2"><?php echo esc_html_x('Add New', 'link'); ?></a></h2>
        <!-- For plugins, we also need to ensure that the form posts back to our current page -->
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page'] ?>" />
        <?php $testListTable->search_box('Search Table', 'your-element-id'); ?>
        <!-- Now we can render the completed list table -->
        <?php $testListTable->display() ?>
    </form>

 </div>
<?php
```

But when I click on ID, I get the Rows Sorted in this way

1   10   11   12   13    2   21 ..etc..

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. Just replace strcmp by strnatcmp in function usort_reorder

```
function usort_reorder($a,$b){
  $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'id'; //If no sort, default to title
  $order = (!empty($_REQUEST['order'])) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc'; //If no order, default to asc
  $result = strnatcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]); //Determine sort order
  return ($order==='asc') ? $result : -$result; //Send final sort direction to usort
}
```